# Assigning a 'day counter' for objects with DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime, group-by

I have a list of `Order` objects with a property `OrderDate` of type `DateTime` and I am trying to assign a 'DayCounter' for these objects that represents what order of the day it was, for example one day, I have 5 orders so every order gets a counter from 1 up to 5.

Here is what I tried:

```
 orders.GroupBy(order => order.OrderDate.DayOfYear + order.OrderDate.Year)
.SelectMany(group =>
{
    var count = 1;
    group.Select(order =>
    {
        order.DayCounter = count;
        count++;
        return order;
    });
    return group;
});
```

the `Order` objects I get from this code all have DayCounter of 0
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: For your grouping you might be better using `order.OrderDate.Date`, your current method consider January 2nd 2014 and January 1st 2015 to be the same day (both use the value `2016` for their group number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ is not for modifying data, it is for selecting and projecting data. Your `Select` never gets run because `Select` is a lazy method and you never iterate over it. Use a normal `foreach` instead.

```
var groups = orders.GroupBy(order => order.OrderDate.Date);
foreach (var grouping in groups)
{
    int orderCount = 1;
    foreach (var order in grouping)
    {
        order.DayCounter = orderCount;
        orderCount++;
    }
}
```

I also changed your grouping key to be a more reliable seperator `OrderDate.Date`, your old method would consider days that are a year minus one day apart to be the same day.

Comment: Indeed, forcing the evaluation of the `Select` method did the trick, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Try using the overload of `.Select` which takes the index as a second parameter.

```
orders.GroupBy(order => order.OrderDate.DayOfYear + order.OrderDate.Year)
.SelectMany(group =>
{
    group.Select((order,idx) =>
    {
        order.DayCounter = idx + 1;
        return order;
    });
    return group;
});
```

Comment: The `% 5` is not needed, he only said "one to five" because there was 5 total orders in his example. To get what he wants you would want `DayCounter = idx + 1` (because `idx` is 0 indexed and he wants `1` indexed)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'm just not sure how this resolves the OP's problem.

Comment: OHHH!, the problem is `Select` is lazy, he never enumerates it never does the code.

Comment: GroupBy is lazy too, so if you never enumerate that it would not evaluate either.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain But at some point he will enumerate. Shouldn't that cause an enumeration of both the GroupBy and Select?

Comment: I used `ToArray()` like this: `group.Select((order, idx) => ...).ToArray()` and `retrun group.ToArray()` not worring for now about performance

Comment: @ZaidAjaj How did you read the result of `orders.GroupBy` initially? Didn't you use a `foreach`, or `.ToArray`? At that point it should have enumerated both the `Select` and the `GroupBy`.